# Problem with dependencies in m2eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, m2eclipse, nexus

I have a problem with m2eclipse and Nexus. Normally, when you create a new Maven Project in Eclipse, you can select an Archetype like maven-archetype-quickstart from the Nexus Indexer. Unfortunately, the Nexus Indexer doesn't show anything at all. But the worst part about all this is, that the "Add Dependency" menue doesn't work. (For a better understanding: By clicking on the "Dependencies" tab, you can usually click on a button in order to enter a groupId or artifactId. That's the menue what I am talking about. If I enter for example "junit", it shows no search results.) 
Does anybody know this issue? How could I fix it?

Thanks a million in advance for any help.

Comment: Add the Error Log View (Window > Show View > Error Log) and see if you can spot an obvious problem.

Comment: Yes, there are a few errors, saying: Unable tor update index for http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, error updating index.
I googled a lot but couldn't solve the problem. Does anybody know this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. I also tried replacing my settings.xml which triggers eclipse to reindex, but no avail.

Comment: Also, the "updating indexes" task seems to hang on central http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Answer (score 1):

By default the ui shows the internal index, select the drop down and choose the Nexus Index if you haven't. Otherwise have you published the index from Nexus?

Comment: When I select the drop down, there are three options: Nexus Indexer, Internal and Default Local. I chose the Nexus Indexer. The filter is empty. However it doesn't show any Group Id or Artifact Id. The window bewlow the catalog and filter options remains empty.
What do you mean with: "Otherwise have you published the index from Nexus?" How can I pubish the index from Nexus?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I thought it was a bug in a m2eclipse plugin. But I found another explanation and solution:
http://forums.jfrog.org/Artifactory-and-m2eclipse-Unable-to-update-index-for-remote-repos-td5899455.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.